# How to get a response from a called function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

I'd like to receive a response (true or false) from a called function to decide if the function should continue or stop. Look at the following code for better understanding:

```
function function1() {
    function2(); // call function2
    // after called function (here I need true or false, to decide if the function should stop or continue)
}

function function2() {
    if (condition === value) {
        // do something, give function1 a response to continue
    } else {
        // do something, give function1 a response to stop
    }
}
```

Updated:

```
function function1() {
    console.log('call function2');
    function2(); // call function2
    // after called function (here I need true or false, to decide if the function should stop or continue)
    console.log('back from function2');
}

function function2() {
    if (condition === false) {
        console.log('condition === false');
        return;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are those functions synchronous?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an else on the statement. check to see if your variable is false and if it is it will return if not the rest of your function will run automatically.

```
function function1() {
function2(); // call function2
// after called function (here I need true or false, to decide if the function should stop or continue)
}

function function2() {
if (condition === false) {
    return;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for you response, but I need a value returned to decide if **function1** should continue.

Comment: using return will exit out of the function thats why you are just saying return and nothing after it. It's not returning any value

Comment: I just updated the question with your example. Can you explain me why I still get **back from function2**?

Comment: I'm posting a new solution now my friend.

Answer (score 0):

If function2 is synchronous you can just return:

```
function function1() {
  if(!function2()){
    return
  }; // call function2
  // after called function (here I need true or false, to decide if the function should stop or continue)
}

function function2() {
  if (condition === value) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

If function 2 does something asynchronous and expects a callback (one of the tags in your question) then it may be easier to write a function that will use function2 and returns a promise.

```js
function function1(condition) {
  console.log('calling function 2');
  function2AsPromise(condition).then(function(
    function2Result
  ) {
    if (!function2Result) {
      console.log('function 2 result is false');
      return;
    }
    console.log('function 2 result is true');
  });
  console.log('exiting function 2');
}

function function2(condition, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (condition) {
      callback(true);
    } else {
      callback(false);
    }
  }, 2000);
}

function function2AsPromise(condition) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    function2(condition, resolve);
  });
}

function1(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const function1 = check => {
   if (check === false) {
     return;
   } else {
   console.log("back from function2");
 }
};


function1(false) // console.log doesn't run
function1(true) // console.log runs
```

make sure that you pass in a Boolean value.

Comment: if this is the solution you are looking for please mark as answer